# Vector of vector : Segmentation Fault

Tags: c++

I have a segmentation fault error at runtime, here is my code with an indication of the line where the error occurs :

EDIT : the variable Scenario is an attribute of the class Probleme, the code I posted is the code of its constructor

EDIT : **The error happens at runtime**

```
class scenario
{
public:
    int id;
    std::vector<std::vector<int> > demandes;

    scenario() {}
    void setid(int i) { id=i; }
    void setdemande( std::vector<int>  v) { demandes.push_back(v); }
    int getid() const { return id; }
};

Scenario.resize(nb_scenario);
for (int i = 0; i < nb_scenario; ++i)
{
    Scenario[i].setid(i);
}
    int s;

    for(int i=0; i<nb_periode ; i++) {
        fichier >> s ;
        for(int j=0;j<nb_produit;j++){
            fichier >> s ;
                for(int k=0;k<nb_scenario;k++){
                    fichier >> s;
                    Scenario[k].demandes[j][i]= s; //Error here
                }
        }                
    }
```

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question with a [mcve] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: Also, format your code so it is legible and get your nomenclature right. I seriously doubt that GCC is segfaulting just from crappy code.

Comment: How about replacing the subscription operator `[]` with `std::vector::at`? 
Also I doubt you get a segfault at compile time, since you're program isn't running then (but your compile, hence the name)

Comment: When posting questions about build errors, always include the exact, complete and unedited error output, including any informational messages.

Comment: @underscore_d As I said, the error I get is "segmentation fault", there is no need for speculation here...

Comment: `demandes[j][i]` - what? this is a 1d vector, not 2d. trying to access it via 2 subscripts probably results in jumping to memory beyond its allocated range, hence the segfault. also, I reiterate my recommendation to reverse your current convention for naming types vs instances; even the SO code formatter thinks your `Scenario` instance is a type, for example.

Comment: When do you set the size of `demandes`? Calling `operator[]` with an out of bounds index is undefined behavior.

Comment: Your vectors are empty, or don't have enough elements. When you try to access `demandes[j][i]`, `demandes.size() == 0` so segmentation fault. Add a check to make sure `j < demandes.size() && i < demandes[j].size()`.

Comment: I think you might have found the issue @Kevin , can you tell me how I should set the size of `demandes` ?

Comment: There is a hint elsewhere in your own code...

Comment: @Neo `demandes.resize(X)` like all other vectors, or use `push_back` to add elements to the end and allow vector to resize itself. You also need to resize the internal vectors (loop over and resize each of them).

Comment: @Neo, what @Sorin said, though instead of looping to resize the internal vectors you could also do `demandes.resize(N, std::vector<int>(M))` to resize to an N*M 2d vector.

Comment: @Kevin why not make that an answer so this question does not fall victim to a drive by copy the comments answer or worse goes into the unanswered bit bucket

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never add anything to the `demandes` vector. Calling `operator[]` on an empty vector (the index is always out of bounds) is undefined behavior.

To fix this add elements to `demandes` using `push_back` or `resize`. To resize the inner vectors at the same time you can do `demandes.resize(N, std::vector<int>(M))`. Also consider using `at` instead of `operator[]`, since it will throw an exception on an out of bounds access instead of causing undefined behavior.